# How to merge all parquet files in a folder along with their meta data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parquet, pyarrow

I am trying to merge a couple of parquet files inside a folder to a dataframe along with their respective meta data. I have the code for converting all parquet to dataframe but I am not able to find a solution to get the meta data out of each parq files. Any help is appreciated. Thank you

[Image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edQG6.png)

#code

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd

data_dir = Path(r'C:\python\Datas\parq\Merged') 
full_df1 = pd.concat(                       
     pd.read_parquet(parquet_file)
     for parquet_file in data_dir.glob('*.parquet'))

full_df1.to_csv('csv_file_lat.csv')
```

I tried to merge the parque but I am clueless on how to merge meta data

Update :

```
 data_dir = Path(r'C:\python\Datas\parq\Merged')
 for i, parquet_path in enumerate(data_dir.glob('*.parquet')):
     df = pd.read_parquet(parquet_path)
     pt = pq.read_table(parquet_path)
     meta_own = json.loads(pt.schema.metadata[b'ais'])
     dff=pd.json_normalize(meta_own)
     fin = pd.concat([df,dff],axis = 1)
     fin.to_csv('testda.csv',mode=write_mode,header=write_header)
```

I tried to implement a for loop using glob and iterate through the folder of parquet files and at the same time I am trying to extract the meta information of the same row but now I am stuck on how to add the parquet file details and the meta data where both are dataframes generated in the for loop as it iterates together.

Comment: Don't post images of your code or data. It makes reproducing the problem harder and undermines your chance of getting an answer.

Comment: Sorry @alibakhtiari I am new to this platform.

Comment: You can use `pd.merge()` or `df.merge()`. Read more on https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html.

Comment: It's fine. Try some code, post it here, and let me know if you had a problem.

Comment: Please provide your code in the question, not on an image somewhere else.

Comment: @chrimaho I need 10 reputations to post images in the forum.I joined stack overflow today.

Comment: No worries, you actually don't need to add an image at all. Please follow the instructions for [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [how to provide a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and [how to format code chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).